# How can I configure which filetypes can be opened by dragging to an application's launcher?

Tags: unity, launcher, shortcuts, .desktop

When we drag some file from some web page or Nautilus towards the launcher, the application that in which it can be coppied remains highlighted and others fade out.

So where is this configuration file that decides which file can be dragged to which application in the launcher?

For example, right now, only a file of some document type can be dragged to [Gwoffice](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/07/gwoffice-integrates-google-docs-with-the-ubuntu-desktop) and some binary file or deb file cant be drag and dropped. So how do I allow suppose a deb file to be draged and droped to Gwoffice.

That was just an example... I want to know how its done in general too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no general configuration file for that behavior. The launchers for the programs themselves, define which MIME types they can open, as per the [FreeDesktop Desktop Entry Spec](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html).

The reason you can't drag a .deb file to gwoffice for example, is because the program has no idea how to handle it, and if you did drag it to the launcher, it wouldn't work, even if you edited the launcher such that you could successfully drag it there.

Comment: "*The launchers for the programs themselves, define which MIME types they can open.*" This answer would be improved by explaining exactly how to specify in a `.desktop` file (since that's how a launcher is implemented) what MIME types the application can open.